# I would like to connect to the Microsoft exchange mail with outlook, I can do it in iphone, but cant in outlook

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I have a exchange mail account, I can connect it through https://mail.abc.com/owa  web portal.
and I can connect to it by setting in phone:
email address: sleepy@abc.com
server: mail.abc.com
domain: XYZ
username: sleepyZzz

However, when I try to connect it via outlook, it keeps tell me the server is cannot connected.
and the outlook does not have the "domain" setting for me.
I tried on both outlook 2003 and 2013 :(

Could I have some ideas about this? I never use exchange mail before.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to validate your configuration:

```
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I asked the IT team and them ask me to use live mail, it is working fine now ;)